# setPrefferedSize not working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, preferredsize

I've been creating a program for login screen with JFrame and I seem to get long bars of login and cancel(using grid layout(2,1,10,10). so I've created small buffer labels within grid layout and changed it to 2,3,10,10 with 4 buffers in the grid. I've used that because the setPreferredSize syntax wasn't working. can you give me the working PrefferedSize syntax for Login and cancel?
here's my initialization code with the buffer labels

```
public class access implements ActionListener
{
boolean flag=false;
JFrame frame;
JTextField username;
JPasswordField password;
JButton login,clear;
JPanel panel1,panel2,panel3;
JLabel user,pass,output,b1,b2,b3,b4;
String[] details;
access()
{
    frame = new JFrame("authentication ");
    panel1= new JPanel();
    panel2= new JPanel();
    panel3= new JPanel();
    username=new JTextField(10);
    password=new JPasswordField(10);
    b1=new JLabel("");
    b2=new JLabel("");
    b3=new JLabel("");
    b4=new JLabel("");
    user= new JLabel("username : ");
    pass= new JLabel("password : ");
    output=new JLabel("  ");
    login=new JButton("login");
    login.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 10));
    clear= new JButton("clear");
    clear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
    login.addActionListener(this);
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    initialize();
}
public void initialize()
{


    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,10,10));
    panel1.add(user);
    panel1.add(username);
    panel1.add(pass);
    panel1.add(password);

    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3,5,5));
    panel2.add(b1);
    panel2.add(login);
    panel2.add(b2);
    panel2.add(b3);
    panel2.add(clear);
    panel2.add(b4);

    panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel3.add(output);

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,10,10));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel3);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,180);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you considered using a [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) instead? Your dialog looks simple enough to use one.

Answer (score 3):

`GridLayout` ignores preferred size. Use another `LayoutManager` e.g. `GridBagLayout`